# How do I draw CCG derivations in LaTeX?

Tags: computational-linguistics, latex

I have been trying to find an easy way to draw CCG derivations in Latex but nothing seems to work. I am working on a presentation, and I found this github [repo](https://github.com/bozsahin/ccg-latex) but it for some reason when I try it it doesn't work. I am using Overleaf and I am a beginner with latex, but I really need to figure this out for a computational syntax course.

Comment: I did my PhD in an area of Combinatory Categorial Grammar. In the course of writing up, I adapted the `.sty` file you've linked to. It should work pretty well as it was designed not to have any LaTeX dependencies. Can you edit your question to give some idea of how you attempted to use it, and how it didn't work for you? It could be that you're using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like what `$\frac{\frac{the}{NP/N}\ \frac{dog}{N}}{NP}$` gets you?

If so, a few notes:

- LaTeX has two main modes - regular mode and math mode. The thing I would do, if I am understanding you correctly, only works in math mode. You can use `$` to toggle inline, `\[` and `\]` do math mode on a separate line.
- `\frac{A}{B}` gets you A over B. These can be nested.
- `\` (backslash space) gets you a space, but a regular space in math mode does not appear (it is used to show you are done with an escaped sequence (one set off with a `\`)
- to make a backslash character, you I think need to do `\backslash`